# Lists created in subsites are not visible in parent intranet site

Tags: list, import

I`m deeply confused as why lists created in subsite example:

`http://intranet.abc.com/projects` are visible in its respective site content:

```
http://intranet.abc.com/projects/_layouts/15/viewlists.aspx
```

Saved all lists as template and uploaded to the solution section under Site Settings (Top Level)

Still trying to add a new app from the site content of Intranet parent site example: `http://intranet.abc.com/_layouts/15/viewlists.aspx`, doesn’t gives option to add new app based on the lists created in subsites.

Wondering what more to do in order to import the lists to the main site apart from uploading in the solution section.

Comment: Did you activate the uploaded solutions (there's a button in the ribbon for that)?

Comment: Hi Robert,

I dont get the option to activate the solution. I know its required to use it. But in my case only option available under Solution post upload is delete, 

Activate and Deactivate are greyed out.

Wondering why, I guess it would be permission isue. But I`ve Site Level Administration powers.

Any suggestions

Comment: Please check, or ask SharePoint farm admins, to see if the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service" is started? Without that service enabled you cannot activate your solutions/templates.

Comment: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service" is enabled, we even stop / start the service from central admin, still the same.